# Union all and maintain active record relations?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This is my query

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT id as broadcast_id, null as message_id, company_id, title, category, publish_at as created_at, image_file_name, null as is_featured, summary, video_link, file FROM broadcasts
UNION ALL
SELECT null, id, company_id, title, 'user_video', created_at, cover_photo_file_name, is_featured, content, video_link, null  FROM `messages` WHERE video_link is not null  and video_link != '')my_table
ORDER BY created_at DESC LIMIT 15
```

I want to maintain everything as Broadcast active-record relation.

I actually got this working using the active record extended gem

```
    legacy_broadcasts = Broadcast.select(:id, "null as message_id", :publish_at, :company_id, :title, :category, :image_file_name, :summary, "null as is_featured", :file, :video_link, :url)
    user_videos       = Message.select("null", :id, :created_at, :company_id, :title, "\"user_video\" as category", :cover_photo_file_name, :content, :is_featured, "null as file", :video_link, "null as url").where('video_link is not null  and video_link != \'\'')
    base              = Broadcast.union_all(legacy_broadcasts, user_videos)
                                 .includes(:company)
                                 .published
                                 .order(publish_at: :desc)

    @q                = base.ransack(params[:q])
    @video_broadcasts = base.has_video_link
                            .paginate(
                              page:     page,
                              per_page: 5)
                            .to_a

    @broadcasts = @q
                    .result
                    .paginate(
                      page:     page,
                      per_page: 9)
                    .to_a
```

but I'm not allowed to add the pg gem into prod that is required by the active recorded extended gem unfortunately. Any idea on how I can best accomplish this?

Comment: Since you are doing a "`UNION ALL`", you could make two queries and sort it in ruby.  Because it is a `UNION ALL` the database cannot take advantage of an index for sorting so it has to do a NlogN sort, which you could do in ruby with a `sort_by` method call.

Answer (score 2):

What I did was use the gem and copy the query it created. From there I did the following

```
    legacy_broadcasts = Broadcast.select(:id, "null as message_id", :publish_at, :company_id, :title, :category, :image_file_name, :summary, "null as is_featured", :file, :video_link, :url).includes(:company).to_sql
    user_videos       = Message.select("null", :id, :created_at, :company_id, :title, "\"user_video\" as category", :cover_photo_file_name, :content, :is_featured, "null as file", :video_link, "null as url").where('video_link is not null  and video_link != \'\'').includes(:company).to_sql
    base              = Broadcast.from("(((#{legacy_broadcasts} ) UNION ( #{user_videos} ))) broadcasts")
                                 .includes(:company)
                                 .published
                                 .order(publish_at: :desc)
```

Comment: Also take a look to [`.find_by_sql`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Querying.html#method-i-find_by_sql), which it will allow you to use full SQL syntax and do something like `Broadcast.find_by_sql('SELECT * FROM...`

Comment: @AlterLagos That works but it return an array, I wanted to maintain the ransack functionality

Comment: Be careful switching from "UNION ALL" to "UNION".  The database can do less work to return "UNION ALL".  Maybe by ordering it, the database will use the order to eliminate the duplicates but there is a good chance it will not and just do the work of removing duplicates which is a lot of work for it to do.